# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://askubuntu.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Anyone can check the results of the election with [openstv](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openstv) [Install openstv http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openstv)

Answer (score 5):

The results from OpenSTV

```
Ballot file contains 7 candidates and 145 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 145 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Ask Ubuntu Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
7 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|Marco Ceppi   |Stefano Palazz|Oli           |fluteflute    |George Edison 
  |              |o             |              |              |              
  |--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
  |txwikinger    |dustyprogramme|Exhausted     |Surplus       |Threshold     
  |              |r             |              |              |              
=============================================================================
 1|     27.000000|     36.000000|     48.000000|     11.000000|     11.000000
  |      9.000000|      3.000000|      0.000000|     11.749999|     36.250001
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Oli has reached the threshold and is
  | elected.
=============================================================================
 2|     30.182283|     41.140611|     36.250032|     12.223955|     12.223955
  |      9.734373|      3.244791|      0.000000|      4.890641|     36.250001
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who
  | have exceeded the threshold: Oli, 0.755209. Candidate Stefano Palazzo has
  | reached the threshold and is elected.
=============================================================================
 3|     30.671865|     41.140611|     37.005241|     12.223955|     14.223955
  |      9.734373|              |      0.000000|      5.645850|     36.250001
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating dustyprogrammer and transferring votes. All
  | losing candidates are eliminated.
=============================================================================
 4|     32.886318|     36.535217|     37.305322|     13.561330|     14.543619
  |     10.137237|              |      0.030957|      1.356017|     36.242261
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who
  | have exceeded the threshold: Stefano Palazzo, 0.881125 and Oli, 0.739796.
=============================================================================
 5|     35.384272|     38.985283|     38.872858|     15.821534|     15.543619
  |              |              |      0.392434|      5.554357|     36.151892
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating txwikinger and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
=============================================================================
 6|     37.579762|     37.167398|     36.724667|     16.905886|     15.971112
  |              |              |      0.651175|      3.210206|     36.087207
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who
  | have exceeded the threshold: Stefano Palazzo, 0.817087 and Oli, 0.688013.
  | Candidate Marco Ceppi has reached the threshold and is elected.

Winners are Marco Ceppi, Stefano Palazzo, and Oli.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Congratulations to our new Ask Ubuntu overlords!

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Many thanks to our Moderators Pro Temp who are stepping down!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I still wish we could have elected more than three!

Comment: Kudos to the Moderators Pro Temp!! They've done a great job!