# What's going on with this revision count?

Tags: support

On [this question page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/910/2011-community-moderator-election) it is said there have been three revisions. If you [look at the history](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/910/revisions) it is clear there have only been two. What's going on?

#### Screenshot 1:

[image]

#### Screenshot 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because this question was programmatically inserted at election start.

Comment: Okay that sounds the likely reason. I don't understand why that would result in it having more revisions though? If anything I would have imagined it having less revisions...